# Making Tkinter window a child of non-Tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, winapi

(This question was [originally posted](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2013-October/003506.html) to python-tkinter mailing list.)

TL;TR How to set Tkinter window's master from `HWND` on Windows?

I'm using Tkinter in embedded Python interpreter on Windows.
There is a desktop Win32 application with a main window opened.
The embedded Python runs a script which creates and displays a Tkinter window.

Is there any way to assign master (parent) of Tkinter window based on `HWND` of a Win32 window?

I'd like to make the Tkinter window a fully modal window in regard to the main Win32 application window.

I know the `winfo_*` APIs wiht `winfo_id()` which allows me to query Win32 `HWND` of Tkinter window, but there seems to be no similar function to set parent by `HWND` (or id on non-Windows OS).

One of ideas I've got is to create a small Python extension, available from my embedded Python, with exposed custom function to overwrite `HWND` of Tkinter windows's parent, using the Win32 [`SetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541.aspx).

Here is some sort of a pseudo-code of the idea:

```
PyObject * mywin32_set_parent(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{

  /* unpack Tkinter HWND from args */
  HWND hTkinterWindow = ... ;

  /* returns main application window */
  HWND hAppWindow = GetMyAppWindow();

  /* make the main window parent of the Tkinter */
  ::SetParent(hTkinterWindow, hAppWindow)

  Py_INCREF(Py_None);
  return Py_None;
}
```

And then in Python script code executed by the embedded Python:

```
import mywin32
root = Tk()
hwnd  = root.winfo_id()
# make root a child of the main application window overwriting its parent
mywin32.set_parent(hwnd)
```

To simplify, let's assume the only purpose of setting master from `HWND` is to position the Tkinter window relatively (or on top) to the window which `HWND` is assigned as master.
IOW, the Tkniter window would behave like a modal dialog of non-Tkinter window.

Is there any Tkinter idiomatic way to achive such behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried using Toplevels?

Comment: @DanielAlexander no, I don't think so.

Comment: Well look into them, they might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Have you figured it out? @mloskot

Comment: @demberto No, I have not, I'm afraid.